# I'm getting a communication link failure on my dockerised spring app using mysql db

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    image: umc:0.0.1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/umc?autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: umc
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: admin@umc
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: docker-mysql
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin@umc
      MYSQL_DATABASE: umc-db
      MYSQL_USER: umc-admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin@umc
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
#      PMA_PORT: 3306
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This is the error: I tried using the local db but it did not work.

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: can you change `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: umc` to `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: umc-admin`. ?

Comment: l got an error about Communication link failure emanating from the database